# How to add an enum member to an openpyxl worksheet

Tags: python, enums, openpyxl

I've got some code which uses openpyxl to write data to a spreadsheet, but it uses some magic strings:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append(["foo", 1, 2, 3])
wb.save('filename.xlsx')
```

but I'd like that "foo" to be an enum member, like this:

```
import openpyxl
from enum import Enum

class Thing(Enum):
    FOO = "foo"

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append([Thing.FOO, 1, 2, 3])
wb.save('filename.xlsx')
```

I'd expect to get the same output, but I actually get:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert <Thing.FOO: 'foo'> to Excel
```

Is there any way to get openpyxl to accept enum members, and just write out their values?

Comment: `str(Thing.Foo)`?

Comment: Well, yeah that would work here, but in the real code I don't know what's in the list I'm appending, and I want things like dates/booleans to be in Excel properly, not in string form.

Comment: openpyxl can handle Python data types.